# grails: how to properly edit/update a collection?

Tags: grails

I just wasted half a day trying to figure this out, reading about some workarounds, and thinking "it can't be that bad - there must be a straightforward to do edit a collection in Grails, whethere using scaffolded views or my own."

Let's say I have this domain object:

```
class TreeGroup {
    String name
    List<Tree> trees      

    static hasMany = ['trees': MyTree]
}
```

Just to explain the choice of data structure - I need my records to be unique, but in the order I set. That's why I chose List, AFAIK one cannot rely on order in a Set. So there are 2 pieces to this question - 1) how to remove from any Collection, for example a Set, 2) is List the best replacement for Set in this context (preserving order).

I want to be able to create a group record with no trees in it and make 4 updates:

- edit/save
- edit the group record to reference 2 trees A and B
- add another tree C
- remove A
- remove B and C

And obviously, I want the desired state after every step. Currently though, I can only add records, and if I even edit/save to list, the list elements are added to it again.

I am using the multiple select tag for this. It looks like this:

```
<g:select name="trees" from="${allTrees}" optionKey="id" 
          multiple="true" class="many-to-many"
          value="${trees ? trees*.id : treeGroupInstance?.trees*.id}" />
```

and that's fine, in the sense that it generates an HTTP header with these variables on update:

```
_method:PUT
version:19
name:d5
trees:1
_action_update:Update
```

But the data binder only adds new elements, it never lets you edit a list.

What is the cleanest way to do it ? Is it me, not reading something obvious, or is this a  design flaw of grails data binding (and of so, when/how will it be fixed) ?

Is there a way perhaps via a hidden HTTP parameter to clear the list before (re)adding elements ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show some controller code? Is the binding portion just `treeGroupInstance.properties = params`?

Comment: I'm trying to use the scaffolding controller, which defines save and update to take TreeGroup as parameter:  def update(TreeGroup treeGroupInstance) and the code there is pretty much limited to treeGroupInstance.save(flush:true) (besides null/error handling). So all binding happens before the controller method is called and what I'm asking for is a way to influence the standard Grails binding to do the right thing.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't realize you could pass an instance into a controller like that. Does `TreeGroup` implement `Serializable`? Have you tried machining your code (e.g., doing a `println treeGroupInstance` at the beginning of the method)? It's primitive but I find it useful and often faster than fiddling with a debugger.

Comment: No, it's not Serializable. I'm afraid it's not about my code, because I don't do anything fancy. Just 2 simple Gorm classes: SecondOne having a Collection<FirstOne> in it + scaffolding. I should be able to open+save an object and the collection should remain intact, I should also be able to edit the collection. But the way things are, the collection elements will be re-added upon save and this is wrong; I'm looking for a clean workaround. I debugged it and I saw where in SimpleDataBinder it adds new elements - it isn't clear to me how to prevent it or rather clear the collection first.

Comment: Again, I find it interesting that you're passing an instance into the controller and not an id. That's different than the scaffolding that the Grails scripts generate. How do you know for certain that this should work?

Comment: Also, what version of Grails? It is changing constantly.

Comment: In grails 2.3.7 and 2.4.2, which I tried, the following methods take instance of domain objects in scaffolding-generated controllers: show, save, edit, update, delete. So, it's not my invention.

Comment: Ah, that must be new since 2.2.0.  Fwiw, my opinion is that you're just going to have to write out the logic that you want. I'm obviously not a Grails expert, but my experience has been that the magic usually only extends so far.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this:

```
private repopulate(def domainObject, String propertyName, Class domainKlaz) {
    if (params[propertyName] != null) {
        domainObject[propertyName].clear()
        domainObject[propertyName].addAll(
              params[propertyName].collect { domainKlaz.get(it) }
        )
    }
}
```

and I am calling it in update controller method before save(), for every collection. OMG how ugly.